# "BOOTMGR is missing" while trying to boot off usb

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, linux-mint

everyone.

here's the problem:
 I made a bootable USB stick to boot Linux mint using Unetbootin.

When I tried to boot off it, though, the following message came:

```
BOOTMGR is missing.
press CTRL-ALT-DELETE to reboot.
```

after I pressed CTRL-ALT-DELETE, it booted to windows. I tried booting the USB on my friend's laptop (which is the exact same as mine, Samsung E300) and it worked fine.

can the problem be cause of this?:

Yesterday, I got this message

```
Error: no such partition.
Grub rescue>_
```

and used this to resolve it: http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/

starting from picture 3. can this be the problem? how can I resolve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your system use BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: BIOS, it user Bios to boot.

Comment: Looks like your USB media isn't actually bootable.

Comment: but, as it said, it booted from my USB on my friend's laptop fine

Comment: Did you modify the boot order on your laptop?

Comment: yes, i set it to boot off usb aal the time